# Does each ERC-721 token have its own address?

Tags: solidity, erc-721

I'm trying to create NFTs (non-fungible tokens), but I don't quite understand this part - is each token its own contract? or are all of them stored in the NFT equivalent of a 'balances' mapping in a factory contract? 
If these are both options which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, NFTS are not contracts of their own.

A single NFT is a `uint256` ID, which is mapped to an owner address. In solidity, this would be something like

`mapping(uint => address) tokenIds`

The [spec](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) lists a number of reference implementations, you should probably use one of those rather than roll your own.